# Add time to AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero in iOS

Tags: ios, core-animation, avfoundation

Below is the code for my animation on the layer:

```
CABasicAnimation *flipAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.y"];

    flipAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:-M_PI_2];

    flipAnimation.beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero;

    flipAnimation.duration = 0;

    flipAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];

    flipAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

    flipAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

    [overlayLayer addAnimation:flipAnimation forKey:@"qddq"];
```

Now for the beginTime property, I want my animation to start after some delay.

I have tried `CACurrentMediaTime() + myDelay;` but it does not solve the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

****I **dont** want my animation to start after some delay****
Is that a typo? Because the title of the question makes me think that you want to start your animation after some delay.
If you want to start your animation immediately then `flipAnimation.beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero;` is absolutely correct. If you want to start your animation after some delay then simply do this:

```
flipAnimation.beginTime = delayTime; // double delayTime = 5.0, animation will begin after 5 seconds.
```

Also, I'm not an expert at CoreAnimation, but I think that animation duration should be more than zero

```
flipAnimation.duration = 0; // maybe that's a mistake?
```